# Python: import files from parent dirs or relative path

Tags: python, ipython

Previously, if I need to import files from parent files

I'll do something like

`from .some_module import some_class`

Now I'm using the code from Udacity (https://github.com/udacity/artificial-intelligence-for-trading/tree/master/project/project_1), specifically, in the .ipynb, the import code is

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -r requirements.txt

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import helper
import project_helper
import project_tests
```

But this gives error

`Invalid requirement: '../../requirements.txt'`

and

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-504bb0e8ad18>", line 3, in <module>
    import helper

  File "G:\Udacity - Artificial Intelligence AI for Trading v1.0.0\artificial-intelligence-for-trading-master\project\project_1\helper.py", line 1
    ../../helper.py
```

And when I look the actual files, they simply refer to files like this:

[image]

[image]

Is such practice legit? If this is legit, how can I solve the above errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the python file first, then you need to create the functions :
e.g.

```
def welc(x):
    print("welcome ",x)
```

then save it and name it as you like.
then go to another python file in the same directory as the first one and 
write:

```
import the_first_file_name  #without .py

the_first_file_name.welc("Abdx")
#Output : welcome Abdx
```